# string formats converted to ? by databinding

Tags: android, string, build, android-resources, android-databinding

I have a source code that had used `databinding` for binding anything to views. and I have some `String.format()` in xml layout files like this:

```
<TextView
   ...
   android:text='@{room.bedrooms == 0 ? "اتاق" : String.format("%d اتاق", room.bedrooms)}' />
```

there is no problem when I compile this code on `Linux` or `Windows`. but when I compile it on `Mac` all of hard coded string `اتاق` converted to `?`.
Do you know why?

I decompiled 2 version of `.apk`s that compiled on different OS, you can see the result below:

```
// compiled on Linux:
String format = (8 & j2) != 0 ? String.format("%d اتاق", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(i2)}) : null;
```

vs.

```
// compiled on Mac:
String format3 = (64 & j2) != 0 ? String.format("%d ????????", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(i2)}) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for once:

```
android:text="@{room.bedrooms == 0 ? `اتاق` : String.format(`%s اتاق`, room.bedrooms)}"
```

Comment: it doesn't affect in result :(